# Equation of the circle(s) touching the x-axis at a distance 3 from the origin and having an intercept of length $2\sqrt7$ on the y-axis

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

> Find the equation of the circle(s) touching the x-axis at a distance 3 from the origin and having an intercept of length $2\sqrt7$ on the y-axis, is...

**I want specifically a geometrical method of solving this question.**

This is what I did:

[image]

As you can see, from the diagram that I have assumed that the centre is $(3,y_1)$.
For the points, the circle intercepts the y-axis, x=0.

So the questions that want answers for are:

1. Is the assumption I have made correct? *(Just a bit unsure about it.)*
2. How do I find the value of $y_1$?
3. How to find the length of the radius?

Comment: there are two circles, you only sketch one ; why ? also if we take into account that the intercept is just a length then there will be four circles :)

Comment: well you have two equations for sure, they include that the difference of roots for $y$ when $x = 0$ is $2 \sqrt{7}$ and other from tangency

Comment: Apply the pythagorean theorem to find the distance from the y-axis.

Comment: @AdityaGarg This is just a sample circle to visualize. I know that there is going to one in each quadrant. I only want answers to the questions I have asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there are 4 such circles which satisfy the condition. Ponder:

[image]

Let's focus our attention to only the circle in the first quadrant.

I have hidden the numbers on the axes so that we  don't know the value of $y_1$

Look at the following diagram:

[image]

Convince yourself with the following facts

- $BC=\frac{1}{2}BD=\sqrt{7}$
- $AB=AE=r$
- $AC=3$
- $AB^{2}=AC^{2}+BC^{2}$
- $r=4$
- $y_{1}=4$

Similarly, by symmetry you can find the parameters for the other circles.

Comment: But r=4 does not mean $y_1=4$ here. Look at the diagram

Comment: AE = r = y1 = 4

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

We translate the center of circle to point $(3, \sqrt 7)$, the equation of circle will be:

$$(x-3)^2+(y-\sqrt 7)^2=R^2$$

In this position the circle passes the origin, so we must have:

$$(0-3)^2+(0-\sqrt 7)=R^2$$

Which gives $R=4$  and  $y_1=4$